# How to get a ' to stay in scheme

Tags: scheme, racket

Sorry if the title is kind of weird but I wasn't really sure how to phrase it.  Anyways my project is an object maker and right now I am just formatting everything so it works with eval and I am having trouble translating this statement`(cond ((equal? message 'getx) xval)...)` into my object code maker where message is a command passed in and xval is just a instance variable.  Obviously equal? and message are easy enough just using `'equal?` and `'message` in order to not be evaluated but how do I get the apostrophe to show up?

I'm using Pretty Big in Dr. Racket if that makes a difference

Clarification: 
If I run `(eval (list 'equal? 'message 'getx`)...) it would run as `(equal? message getx)...` and instead I want it to be `(equal? message 'getx)`  I want it to compare message to the symbol `'getx` instead of the reference `getx`.

Comment: Could you try to clarify your question a bit? I could guess what's your issue, but hopefully you can explain it further. Try to produce a minimal test case (code) that shows the behavior you didn't expect.

Comment: For every `'` you are not evaluatng its arguments. `'x` is just sugar for `(quote x)`. eg `(list 'quote 'data)` will display as `'data` or `(quote data)`. Both likely scenarios since they mean the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you just have to quote the whole expression:

```
'(cond ((equal? message 'getx) xval)...)
```

Comment: Just tested it and that's exactly what I needed thanks!